# Manifest merger for my android library

Tags: java, android

I have my library (x) which is dependent on a precompiled aar library (y).  I do not want the users of my library x to include y as dependency, i.e., I would like to provide x as a self sufficient package.

y is a module that contains just the aar from a third party and it bundles layout files, images, classes and a manifest.   When I build my library x, under the following folder
build/intermediates/exploded-aar/y/unspecified/
I see,
AndroidManifest.xml  R.txt  aapt/  aidl/  assets/  jars/  jni/  libs/  res/

I understand that y.aar has been unzipped here and these correctly belong to library y.aar.

However, when x.aar gets generated, I do not see the manifests, resources getting merged and I am not able to understand why?

Doesn't manifest/resource merging work only com.android.application plugin and not for com.android.library?

Any help is really appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is use **transitive dependency**.

For example in your host app:

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:KIT_VERSION@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

It will fetch all dependencies of your dependencies.

Comment: In my case, my library (x.aar) doesn't include activities/receivers/resources from y.aar, i.e., the resources and manifests didn't get merged.

Comment: I don't really understand, can you explain it again ? @Vignesh

Comment: I would like to create an android library (x.aar) that depends on a third party library (y.aar available as a module).  I do not want Apps that uses x.aar to be even aware of y.aar 's presence and just include x.aar.   In my build.gradle to build x.aar, I have added compile project (':y') as a dependency but I see that none of the resources/manifests get merged in x.aar.

Comment: my answer is still valid so, but you'll need to publish your Y library remotely so when the X library will be added, gradle will fetch Y too. I do'nt know another solution.